# How to insert images only by url in CKEditor5 with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I'm trying to insert images solely by url. In CKEditor 5 there is this feature but I'm not sure how can I make the img icon-button open modal to enter url.

this is what I have for now inside CKEditor component config

```
 config={{
      toolbar: ['imageUpload'],
      image: {
        // ...
        upload: {
          panel: {
            items: ['insertImageViaUrl'],
          },
        },
      },
    }}
```

As shown in image below I can upload via url after clicking dropdown menu but more precisely I would like to swap image upload functionality with upload by url functionality from dropdown

[image]

Comment: Here is the relevant pull request: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/pull/11571 but I'm not sure how to set this up

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ImageInsertViaUrl` plugin. It will only allow URLs.

Pull request: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/pull/11980

```js
plugins: ['ImageInsertViaUrl']
toolbar: ['insertImage']
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. The behavior is still the same. I suspect that these plugins shadow each other but they are also interdependent.

Comment: This solution works. Too bad it's missing from their documentation. To make it work, I'm adding `Image` and `ImageInsertViaUrl` in the `plugin` array (and only those images plugins, do not add the `ImageInsert` plugin). In the toolbar, I'm adding `insertImage`. The result is an image button with the dropdown, which looks a bit weird, but when you click on it, you can only add an image via a URL.

Comment: Saved my day! You can add the "AutoImage" plugin as well to paste the URL directly in the editor

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL of an image, the user may easily paste it into the editor. In order to enable this option, install the ImageInsert plugin and add the insertImage toolbar item to the toolbar (it replaces the standard uploadImage button).

```
import ImageInsert from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ ... , ImageInsert ],
        toolbar: [ ... , 'insertImage' ]
    } )
```

This will add a new Insert image dropdown Insert image in the toolbar. To upload the image, click on the image icon. To open the panel and add the image URL, click the arrow next to the image button. Check the demo below to insert a new image via URL or update an existing image by selecting it, opening the dropdown panel and pasting a new URL.

Source => https://cutt.ly/vMU5Ey1

Comment: This is as shown in the question. But the question is how to disable the upload option; such that pressing the button directly will open the URL dialog, not the upload dialog, as in certain scenarios, you want to disable this option (if you don't want to host the images)

Answer (score -1):

The Image plugin registers:

The `insertImage` command that accepts a source (e.g. a URL) of an image to insert.
The ImageUpload plugin registers:

The <kbd>uploadImage</kbd> that opens the native file browser to let you upload a file directly from your disk (to use in the image toolbar).
The `uploadImage` command that accepts the file to upload.

Comment: This is not an answer.